# Debug Android app with Eclipse on real devices

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have attach my real Android device on eclipse and run the debug mode, the application is launch and run on real devices. Toggle Breakpoint is added, but it seem don't hit even is suppose the line is have been run already.

Error is no fix
--> Source Not found
--> Edit Source Lookup Path -> Project -> Select the project -> ok

Comment: did you opened DDMS perspective and have you enabled the USB debugging?

Comment: have u seen u r device in DDMS @ devices tab in online mode. Also have u enabled USB debugging of device

Comment: Some devices (eg samsung) require that you have custom software drivers installed on the PC (for example the samsung tablets require Kies to be installed before the USB integration works).

Comment: the usb integration is install, and when run debug will install and run the program in real device, but source not found even add the project source on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General instructions to follow:

1. Do adb devices in command prompt - are you able to see device - Yes
   then great , else restart adb device/reconnect device/ check drivers
2. Change run configurations of the project(right
   click->Properties->Run As->Run Configurations-> Target)  to prompt
   for device everytime you run. The device should have USB Debugging enabled.
3. Click on the debug icon in your toolbar and choose your device for
   debugging - put break points and voila it should work. Make sure your Breakpoints are in places where the code is generated. Code may not be hit sometimes because thats how the code is

This is for Google Approved devices.